# Telephone input which requires country calling code

Tags: html, input

Is there a HTML form input which accepts only telephone numbers prefixed with a country code e.g. +44 for Great Britain, +359 for Bulgaria?

Comment: use JavaScript to validate user's input.

Comment: I wrote a jQuery plugin to help with this - it has a flag dropdown which you use to select the country code prefix: https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you divide the field into 2 fields: `country-code` (a dropdown with prefix like +44, +359 etc); and a regular number field with remaining of the `phone number`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this jQuery plugin which is fantastic for those cases.: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html

Answer (score 0):

I do know that you can simply do it using javascript, however if you are developing using asp .net, you may use validation controls.